# django user with email as pk - hack possible?

Tags: python, django, authentication

I read a lot about the topic, but didn't find anything that sounded as satisfactory as an idea of mine, and also don't see why it would raise problems. So if you can give it a look...

I want to change user authentication in mid-project, i.e. avoid using a custom user model, since this requires to be done before the first migration.

Can I just modify the email field to `editable=False` in the `django.contrib.user.models` and add a modified `save()`, so the email is updated from the username? Or the other way round? Pro

And another distict general question: Would I do such things in the venv, or can I copy the whole auth-folder as a local app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your title doesn't seem to have anything to do with your question; which is a good thing, because using email as a primary key is an incredibly bad idea. People change email addresses all the time, but a PK must stay constant.

Secondly, you should absolutely not copy the contrib.auth code. Apart from anything else, this wouldn't solve your problems with the migrations, it would just make them worse.

A much better solution would be add a pre-save signal on User, which you can do from anywhere in your project (ideally in an AppConfig `ready` method). And you don't need to change the model in order to make email uneditable; you should do that in the forms that use that model.

Comment: Thank you for the hints; I will look into the concept of the pre-save signal, this will help in other places. But as for this question, I stumbled upon the problem, that username does not allow "@", this probably closes the issue.... Would there be a problem (except recovery of the old data) if I delete the db.sqlite3 and all migrations, and run makemigrations will all settings and apps installed?

Comment: well, I guess i can close this, though it did not solve my question; thank you for the hints