# django good style: copy built-in directory to local project?

Tags: python, django

This is somehow connected to my last question ([django user with email as pk - hack possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42506097/6053327)), but I try another approach:

is it bad practice to copy the full `django.contrib.auth` to my project, and modify files there? I want to use a custom user model, and stumbled upon lots of things to change in permissions, groups, etc, besides the CustomUserManager and my CustomUser. Besides, I dont want to have groups in one app and MyUser in another. Besides, integrating userena needs some furher changes to User...

Will this raise problems besides not being able to upgrade to next django version?

Sorry for asking such an often-asked question, but somehow the manuals and forum posts are too diverse and contradicting to chose from...

Comment: Given that `django.contrib.auth` is full of security-related features -- yes, copying the module and missing out on essential updates is a horrible idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are a number of issues that could potentially arise by copying the full `django.contrib.auth` directory in to your app source - namely with regards to builds.

Why not just extend the user model by using a custom model extending `AbstractBaseUser`?

Something like:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from .managers import UserManager


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars/', null=True, blank=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def get_full_name(self):
        '''
        Returns the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
        '''
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        '''
        Returns the short name for the user.
        '''
        return self.first_name

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        '''
        Sends an email to this User.
        '''
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)
```

There are a number of other options. [Check this out](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html) if you want to see what other options are available.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and code. I have been trying this for some time already, but something is not correct. You have the `auth` still in INSTALLED_APPS, right? And therefore an auth.User and a myapp.User in your db? If I comment the `auth` out, it doesn't find Permissions etc

Comment: Well, somehow it seemed wrong to have two tables, one for my new user, and one for the original auth/User. Besides, the Permissions and Groups are connected to the old Users, aren't they?

Comment: of course I did read it :) but it is a subset of the example in the djano docs, which I have already tried, and even those are without Permissions and Groups. When I try to integrate those features, there are "system check identified some issues"-errors. Something is wrong ;) I now try to chose between populating the username field with random data and digging even further into custom users....

Comment: Well, what custom features are you trying to apply to the user model anyway? Could you not just create another table that had a foreign key relationship to user?

Comment: I have somehow managed it to use a custom model; some points still don't work as I thought, but I'll close this question. Thank you for your support so far!